# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in angular2

Tags: angular

I am using angular2 with typescript in Visual Studio 2015.I am getting exception **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in angular2**

Why i am getting this exception and how can i solve this.

Comment: What version of angular2 are you using? When did it go wrong, what is the code, etc

Comment: i am using    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.8",   In my page there are 50 text box .At the time of render it  getting exception.

Comment: Could you try using the latest RC? There was a known bug in the earlier versions of angular2 which caused this.

Comment: Should i use angular RC1 to solve this issue?

Comment: I would just go for the latest version if that is possible

Answer (score 13):

Might not have been your issue, but worth mentioning.  I was getting the same error with RC5. It took a bit before I realized that it stopped when I commented out one of my modules with the selector "footer".  Well my footer.component.html template file of course uses the HTML5 `<footer>` tag. So because my selector was an HTML tag it was in infinite recursion.  Seems obvious to think about now, but caused me some issues.

Comment: you are  a legend

Comment: you saved my life :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found out that in my `component.html`, I was calling 
the same selector that call my `component.html`, hence recursivity.